# Migrating all the content from Typo3 CMS

Tags: typo3

Is there a way to export the current content (pages and assetts)? if so what format does it export to? I am not familiar with Typo3 as yet so any info would be great. Thanks.

Comment: First of all its TYPO3 not Typo3. Secondly. What for you need to do the export ? You want to migrate to another TYPO3 installation or to diffrent system ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. There is a [tutorial](http://typo3tutorials.com/index.php?id=137) on how to export a site as a t3d file. (Select module "page" in typo3 backend, right click the item in the page tree you want to export and then choose "export to .t3d" from the context menu. There are a lot of options in the further dialog of what you want to have included in your export file. The import process is described there as well.

Comment: NOTES for Mikey: T3D is basically an XML file. Choose the uncompressed version if you do not intend to import it back to TYPO3.

Comment: Note: The tutorial linked in this post is no longer available, and wayback does not have an archive.