# How to export xml or json from typo3

Tags: typo3

I need to export content from a typo3 site to a web app. I am considering to use xml or json. But I haven't figure it out how to do it.

I'm new to typo3 development. So I would like to know if someone has suggestions how to do this.

Regards,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997615/migrating-all-the-content-from-typo3-cms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This highly depends on your requirements ;)

As a starting point you can use a new page type and disable all header codes to generate XML e.g.

```
xml = PAGE
xml {
    typeNum = 123
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        xhtml_cleaning = none
        admPanel = 0
        metaCharset = utf-8 
        additionalHeaders = Content-Type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
    }
    10 = COA
    10 {
        wrap = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?><your_root_tag>|</your_root_tag>
        # add code here to generate xml content
        10 = ...
    }
}
```

If you browse to http://example.com/index.php?type=123 you'll get the XML content.

But if things get more complex writing an extension maybe the better approach.